# How to get identifier of an activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, navigation-drawer

I have a navigation drawer which starts another activity when one of the items is selected. I don't want to start the same activity if that activity is the current activity (if the user selects an option, a new activity is started, and they select the same option again from the menu). How can I tell what the current activity is, so I don't start the same activity over again (instead I simply close the drawer)?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Activities like you would pages in a website then you will need to manage an 'ID' yourself. A constant on each Activity that you check when building the menu(list of activities) might be enough.

It might be better to not use Activities in this way as starting an activity is slow therefore not really ideal for flicking between items in a menu. I'd suggest using fragments. Fragments make it easier to manage state and are faster to load.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, if user is in Activity A and clicks Activity B, B should be rendered. But User is in A and clicks A, nothing should happen.

You can achieve this by setting an ID for each activity and rendering accordingly. But how about setting the activity in Manifest.xml file as singleinstance.

```
<activity 
   android:name=".YourActivity"
   android:launchMode="singleInstance"/>
```

**What you achieve ?**

OS automatically create a new one if no activity exists or bring to the front the currently existing activity (thanks to the singleInstance property).

See if this works for you.

Comment: Just as a heads up, the [documentation on singleInstance contains this note](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html): "The other modes — singleTask and singleInstance — are not appropriate for most applications, since they result in an interaction model that is likely to be unfamiliar to users and is very different from most other applications."